# In Final Fantasy VI what is the best grinding place Pre World of Ruins?

Tags: snes, final-fantasy-6

Details: SNES, Cartridge reads III But apparently its VI Since I'm in America. I've just got to South Figaro (Not my first run) And I need a place to grind so I don't get my ass kicked on Mt. Kolts. (I'm keeping locke dead until I get Odin.)

Comment: There are minimum level runs that can get to world of chaos by level SEVEN, so you probably don't need to grind as much as you think :)

And why are you keeping locke dead?  When you get him again in the world of chao, he'll gain levels based on your party level, so he's not going to stay whatever level you keep him dead.  The minimum level guides will explain how character levelling works also.